# HQL with parameters giving error IllegalArgumentException

Tags: hql, illegalargumentexception

I am getting an exception while trying to fetch some data using HQL with parameters. Below is the exception and the code.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TESTDB.ORDER_DETAILS is not mapped [SELECT DATE,ORDER_NAME,DESCRIPTION FROM TESTDB.ORDER_DETAILS WHERE ORDER_ID = :orderId ORDER BY DATE DESC]

```
//*************************************************************    
OrderDetailDTO orderDetailDTO = new OrderDetailDTO();
List<OrderDetailDTO> orderList = new ArrayList<OrderDetailDTO>();
ResultSet rs = null;

String queryStr = "SELECT DATE,ORDER_NAME,DESCRIPTION "
                    + "FROM TESTDB.ORDER_DETAILS WHERE ORDER_ID = :orderId "
                    + "ORDER BY DATE DESC";
org.hibernate.query.Query query = session.createQuery(queryStr).setParameter("orderId", ordId); 
rs = (ResultSet)query.getResultList();

while(rs.next()!=false){                                
  orderDetailDTO.setOrderName(rs.getString("ORDER_NAME"));                          
  orderDetailDTO.setDescription(rs.getString("DESCRIPTION"));
  orderDetailDTO.setDate(rs.getTimestamp("DATE"));
        
  orderList.add(orderDetailDTO);
}
//*************************************************************    
//ordId : This one I have as argument in the method
```

I have to use this parameterised HQL to avoid SQL injection. Can anyone figure out why the weird error of IllegalArgumentException is comming.

Comment: let me mention one thing..table is already existing and previously ran with other code. The change only made is used hql this time

Answer (score 0):

The solution is done by using the entity names instead of the database table names. There is the catch. In JPQL we need to use the java bean class name in the query. When I replaced the java bean class name with the java bean fields name everything worked fine.

Also in JPQL mentioning the schema name is not required as in case of JPQL hibernate will use the schema
as defined by the hibernate.default_schema configuration property. The URL used for reference is https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-resolve-the-hibernate-global-database-schema-and-catalog-for-native-sql-queries/

Below is the working code :

The java code for the database table :

```
package demo.jpql;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Entity
@Table( name = "ORDER_DETAILS" )
public class OrderDetails  implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column( name = "ORDER_NAME", length = 50 )
    private String orderName;

    @Column( name = "DESCRIPTION", length = 50 )
    private String desc;

    @Column( name = "DATE" )
   private Timestamp    date;

     public String getOrderName() {
      return orderName;
    }
    public void setOrderName(String orderName) {
      this.orderName = orderName;
    }

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
      this.desc = desc;
    }

    public Timestamp getDate() {
      return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Timestamp date) {
      this.date = date;
    }
}


//*************************************************************    
OrderDetailDTO orderDetailDTO = new OrderDetailDTO();
List<OrderDetailDTO> orderList = new ArrayList<OrderDetailDTO>();
ResultSet rs = null;

String queryStr = "SELECT date,orderName,desc"
                + "FROM OrderDetails WHERE orderID =:orderId "
                + "ORDER BY date DESC";
org.hibernate.query.Query query = 
session.createQuery(queryStr).setParameter("orderId", ordId); 

List<Object> rsltLstOrderDtls = (List<Object>)query.getResultList();                
Iterator<Object> itr = rsltLstOrderDtls.iterator();

while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr.next();       
    orderDetailDTO.setOrderName(String.valueOf(obj[1]));                          
    orderDetailDTO.setDescription(String.valueOf(obj[2]));

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
    java.util.Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(String.valueOf(obj[0]));
    Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
    orderDetailDTO.setDate(timestamp);
    
    orderList.add(orderDetailDTO);
}
//*************************************************************
```